# A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the result of call to local:getFirstPublisherUrl

Tags: xml

Estoy intentando conseguir el url de un publisher mediante una función de xQuery, a la función le paso el nombre de un autor que tengo en el documento biblio.xml, y lo que pretendo es que dado ese nombre encuentre el primer pusblisher de un libro escrito por ese autor. La información sobre las url de los publisher esta en el archivo publist.xml este el el código de mi función:

```
declare function local:getFirstPublisherUrl($aut as xs:string) as  xs:string 

{
for $b in doc("biblio.xml")/bib/book[author=$aut]/publisher[position()=1]
for $p in doc("publist.xml")/publist/publisher[pubname=$b]

return
    if($p[puburl])then
        $p/puburl/text()
     else
        " "
};
```

Esta es la llamada a mi función:

```
<ebazpena ariketa="hamabi">
<puburlak>
{
for $aut in distinct-values(doc('biblio.xml')//author)

return 
    <puburl>
    { local:getFirstPublisherUrl(data($aut))  }
    </puburl>
   }
</puburlak>
</ebazpena>
```

Este es mi archivo publist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<publist>
    <publisher>
        <pubname>Addison-Wesley</pubname>
        <pubaddress>Washington</pubaddress>
        <puburl>http://www.addisonwesley.com/index.html</puburl>
    </publisher>
    <publisher>
        <pubname>Morgan Kaufmann Publishers</pubname>
        <pubaddress>New York</pubaddress>
        <puburl>http://www.morgan.com/</puburl>
    </publisher>
    <publisher>
        <pubname>Wiley</pubname>
        <pubaddress>London</pubaddress>
        <puburl>http://www.wiley.uk/</puburl>
    </publisher>
    <publisher>
        <pubname>Springer-Verlag</pubname>
        <pubaddress>Berlin</pubaddress>
    </publisher>
</publist>
```

Y este el archivo biblio.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bib>
    <book year="1994">
        <title>TCP/IP Illustrated</title>
        <author>
            <last>Stevens</last>
            <first>W.</first>
        </author>
        <publisher>Addison-Wesley</publisher>
        <price>65.95</price>
    </book>

    <book year="1992">
        <title>Advanced Programming in the Unix environment</title>
        <author>
            <last>Stevens</last>
            <first>W.</first>
        </author>
        <publisher>Addison-Wesley</publisher>
        <price>65.95</price>
    </book>
    <book year="2000">
        <title>Data on the Web</title>
        <author>
            <last>Abiteboul</last>
            <first>Serge</first>
        </author>
        <author>
            <last>Buneman</last>
            <first>Peter</first>
        </author>
        <author>
            <last>Suciu</last>
            <first>Dan</first>
        </author>
        <publisher>Morgan Kaufmann Publishers</publisher>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bib>
```

El error me lo da en la linea de la funcion:

```
for $b in doc("biblio.xml")/bib/book[author=$aut]/publisher[position()=1]
```

Y dice lo siguiente:

> A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the result of call
>   to local:getFirstPublisherUrl ("http://www.addisonwesley.com/i...",
>   "http://www.addisonwesley.com/i...")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado:

```
declare function local:getFirstPublisherUrl($aut as xs:string) as  xs:string 

{
for $b in doc("biblio.xml")/bib/book[author=$aut]/publisher[position()=1]
let $p in doc("publist.xml")/publist/publisher[pubname=$b]

return
    if($p[puburl])then
        $p/puburl/text()
     else
        " "
};
```

Después del primer for el segundo era un let no un for

Comment: Hola Begoña, si te lo permite ¿podrías marcar la autorespuesta como solución? gracias, me alegro que lo hayas solucionado. Saludos.